# How to check internet range continuously in background service?

Tags: android, android-service, android-networking, android-internet

I want to check whether internet is present or no continuously in background service so that I get broadcast as soon as the device gets connected to internet. Suggest with some snippets. Thank you.

Comment: what did you try up to now?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - detect whether there is an Internet connection available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238921/android-detect-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create class that extends `BroadcastReceiver` , use `ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY` to get connection info.

**Code :**

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CheckConnectivity extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {

    boolean isConnected = arg1.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
    if(isConnected){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Internet Connection Lost", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(context, "Internet Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
   }
 }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.connect.broadcast"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" >

  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

  <application
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
     android:label="@string/app_name" >
       <receiver android:exported="false"
          android:name=".CheckConnectivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
     </receiver>
   </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating Service just create intent-filter with connectivity change [Developer Android](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html)

```
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".YourReceiver"
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
</intent-filter>
```

With your BroadcastReciever:

```
public class YourReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
 @Override
 public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent )
 {

 }
 }
```